# Convert anonymous type to strong type for grouping query?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, anonymous-types

I've pieced together some information from other posts but I'm stuck.

The first part works fine. Basically I query the database using LINQ and then I loop through the results generating a report.

```
Dim results As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of Bud900Reports.tblBud_CONNECT)

If options.Type = reportType.Organization Then
        results = From p In db.tblBud_CONNECTs _
                Where p.TableOldName = "tblFY" & options.FiscalYear And p.DEPTID = options.GroupFilter _
                Order By p.SOURCE_CODE, p.ROW_CODE_903 _
                Select p



    ElseIf options.Type = reportType.Division Then
        'Here is my problem line

End If

For each result in results
    'loop through code generating report
Next
```

Now instead of having three function with alot of dupelicate code, if the reportType is Division I want to run this query and put it into the results set.

```
results = (From p In db.tblBud_CONNECTs _
                  Where p.TableOldName = "tblFY" & options.FiscalYear And p.DIVISION_CODE = options.GroupFilter _
                  Group p By p.DIVISION_CODE, p.SOURCE_CODE, p.ROW_CODE_903 Into _
                  OrigEft = Sum(p.OrigEft), OrigAmt = Sum(p.OrigAmt), ABEft = Sum(p.ABEft), ABAmt = Sum(p.ABAmt) _
                  Order By DIVISION_CODE, SOURCE_CODE, ROW_CODE_903 _
                  Select DIVISION_CODE, SOURCE_CODE, ROW_CODE_903, OrigEft, OrigAmt, ABEft, ABAmt)
```

It's the same data just grouped and summed up. But it comes through as an anonymous type. I tried to do "select new tblBud_CONNECTs with {.DIVISION_CODE = DIVISION_CODE, ...}" but it gave me the error of "Explicit construction of entity type tblBud_CONNECTs is not allowed".

How can I do what I want? It seems that I should be able to. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness I'll answer my own question.

First I created a class to hold the results.

```
Private Class results
    Private mDivCode As String
    Public Property DivCode() As String
        Get
            Return mDivCode

        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            mDivCode = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private mSourceCode As Short
    Public Property SourceCode() As Short
        Get
            Return mSourceCode
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Short)
            mSourceCode = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private mRowCode As Short
    Public Property RowCode() As Short
        Get
            Return mRowCode
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Short)
            mRowCode = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private mOrigEft As Decimal
    Public Property OrigEft() As Decimal
        Get
            Return mOrigEft
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            mOrigEft = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private mOrigAmt As Decimal
    Public Property OrigAmt() As Decimal
        Get
            Return mOrigAmt
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            mOrigAmt = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private mABEft As Decimal
    Public Property ABEft() As Decimal
        Get
            Return mABEft
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            mABEft = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private mABAmt As Decimal
    Public Property ABAmt() As Decimal
        Get
            Return mABAmt
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            mABAmt = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Then I set a variable to hold the results.

```
Dim results As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of results)
```

Then I made my linq query fill up the results like so.

```
results = (From p In db.tblBud_CONNECTs _
                Where p.TableOldName = "tblFY" & options.FiscalYear And p.DEPTID = options.GroupFilter _
                Order By p.SOURCE_CODE, p.ROW_CODE_903 _
                Select New results With {.DivCode = p.DIVISION_CODE, .SourceCode = p.SOURCE_CODE.Value, .RowCode = p.ROW_CODE_903.Value, _
                                         .OrigEft = p.OrigEft.Value, .OrigAmt = p.OrigAmt.Value, .ABEft = p.ABEft.Value, .ABAmt = p.ABAmt.Value})
```

That's how I ended up doing what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a collection of the Division instances and populate this collection using 'results'. 
Then you can use the [Attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.attach.aspx) method to enable change tracking for these entities.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? I don't understand.

Comment: Try code like the following:
Dim list As New List(Of Division)
For Each element in results
  Dim div As New Division With { .DivisionCode = element.DIVISION_CODE, ..., .ABAmt = element.ABAmt}
list.Add(div)
Next
DataContextInstance.Divisions.AttachAll(list)

Comment: Thanks for answering but I never did fully understand what you were trying to say. I ended up using a different method which I've added as an answer to this question.